# Calculating iOS SDK size

Tags: ios, frameworks, sdk, size

I'm building my own iOS framework using this package: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

This may be a very silly question, but how can I calculate the size of my output SDK? In other words, is the `du -sh` size of the .framework directory the canonical "SDK size", or is there some compression that's done after linking the SDK with the app and bundling it that results in a smaller size?

I apologize in advance if my question is unclear, I'd be glad to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with with some developers, the "standard" seems to be to compile an app without your framework, archive to an IPA and look at the size, then do the same but with your framework included and consider the difference in IPA size to be your SDK size.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a products folder in your XCode Project Navigator (the left hand side window)

Expand this and click on the Product, it should show you the size of the product ,in this case the framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, my output framework is not listed under Products (maybe because of the github xcode extension?). Even for ones that are listed, I don't see a size anywhere. Are you talking about when I click "Show in Finder" and then highlight it there?

Comment: Yes, it's still not showing up. I can find the output .framework folder by doing "Show in Finder" for other targets that were built. They're all in the same dir.